# How to determine if the registers are loaded right to left or vice versa

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, att, intel-syntax

When reviewing gdb output and looking at the assembly calls, usually I can find a command using hard-coded values to determine whether the registers are being loaded right to left or vice versa.

Usually something like the following:

```
  sub     rsp, 16
```

or

```
  sub     16, rsp
```

But other times, no values like above are visible. 
All I see are calls like the following :

```
(gdb) disassemble
 Dump of assembler code for function main:
 0x0000000100000f54 <main+4>:    mov    $rdi,%r15
 0x0000000100000f59 <main+9>:    mov    $rsi,%r14
 0x0000000100000f60 <main+16>:   mov    $rdx,%r13
 0x0000000100000f67 <main+23>:   mov    $ecx,$r12d
 End of assembler dump.
```

How does one determine if values are processed left to right or vice versa?

Comment: If the registers have a `%` prefix => AT&T syntax => `src, dst` order. Otherwise, unadorned => Intel syntax => `dst, src`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Normally, Gnu tools use AT&T syntax. You can tell that it is AT&T syntax by the presence of little symbols, like the `$` preceding literals, and the `%` preceding registers. For example, this instruction:

```
sub    $16, %rax
```

is obviously using AT&T syntax. It subtracts 16 from the value in the `rax` register, and stores the result back in `rax`.

In AT&T syntax, the destination operand is on the *right*:

```
insn   source, destination     # AT&T syntax
```

There is also Intel syntax. This is ubiquitous on Windows platforms, and usually also available as an option for Gnu/Linux tools. Intel syntax is *unadorned*—*e.g.*:

```
sub   rax, 16
```

which is the same as the AT&T instruction above—it subtracts 16 from the value in the `rax` register, and stores the result back in the `rax` register.

In Intel syntax, the destination operand is always on the *left*:

```
insn  destination, source     ; Intel syntax
```

To be absolutely certain of which version you've got, you'd need to check the settings for your disassembler/debugger and see what syntax it is configured to use, but it's usually dead-simple to tell at a glance just by looking to see if the symbolic adornments are there (a dead give-away for AT&T syntax).

> **Summary:**
>
> - If the registers have a `%` prefix → AT&T syntax → `src, dst` order.
> - Otherwise, unadorned registers → Intel syntax → `dst, src` order.

If you've somehow ended up looking at code that doesn't use any registers (???), another good heuristic clue is that Intel syntax will prepend size specifiers (like `DWORD`, `QWORD`, and `BYTE`) to the associated operand, whereas AT&T syntax will append a suffix (`l`, `q`, `b`, etc.) to the instruction mnemonic itself.

Comment: For instructions with more than two operands, AT&T syntax reversed the list from Intel.  e.g. `pshufd $0xE4, %src, %dst`.

Comment: I updated the [AT&T tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info) with this info (including links to some good dup targets for common question, using this one as an answer for operand-order)